# Sublim text ! how to select all end of column?

Tags: text, sublimetext

Sublim text ! how to select all end of column ?
i've db how ican select end of all lines
before : 
example 
aaaa:123456
bbbb:123456

i want delete numbers

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please edit your question and express yourself more clearly by writing in coherent English sentences.

Answer (score 3):

If the numbers you wish to delete occur at the end of all the lines:

- Ctrl-A to select all
- Ctrl-Shift-L to split into lines
- Press the End key
- Ctrl-Shift Left to select the last word (the numbers)
- Press the Delete key

Rather than Ctrl-Shift-Left and Delete, you can just press Ctrl-Backspace (deleting the word(s) to the left).

If you just want to delete ALL numbers from the document (which may not be at the end of each line) then use the Replace feature, using a regex expression.

**Added**: To do this, press Ctrl-H or choose the Find menu, Replace.. Click the button to the far-left of the `Find What:` box - this enables Regular Expressions; type `\d+` in the `Find What` box and press Replace All. This will replace (remove) all sequences of one or more numbers.

Comment: iforge somehting i use linux ubuntu

Comment: just i want delete all numbers :)

Comment: @user1084433 I've added-to my answer.